# Xcode 6.1 Instruments - Crashes on startup

Tags: xcode6, instruments

Instruments constantly crashes on startup, regardless of project or build settings. 
I've tried removing and re-installing xcode, including the new beta versions. 
I've cleaned the derivedData folder and alll other traces of xCode I could find.
Ive also tried repairing my disk permissons and performed general cleanups.

The crash report looks like this:
Process:               Instruments [3362]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Instruments
Version:               6.1 (56160)
Build Info:            Instruments-56160000000000000~1
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Instruments [3362]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-02-12 18:25:37.655 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        CBFA7BC0-881F-36BF-D5B1-E3E4FDE06A0E

Time Awake Since Boot: 870 seconds

Crashed Thread:        6  Dispatch queue: DebugSymbolsPathWatcherQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000010537aff8

VM Regions Near 0x10537aff8:
    Stack                  00000001052f8000-000000010537a000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 5
--> STACK GUARD            000000010537a000-000000010537b000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 6
    Stack                  000000010537b000-00000001053fd000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 6

Thread 6 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: DebugSymbolsPathWatcherQueue

```
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib        0x00007fff8fa68f9c tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 8
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib        0x00007fff8fa67f50 szone_malloc_should_clear + 317
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib        0x00007fff8fa67877 malloc_zone_malloc + 71
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib        0x00007fff8fa66395 malloc + 42
4   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff9043533b __opendir_common + 56
5   com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddba77 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 311
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
7   com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
8   com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
9   com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
10  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
11  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
12  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
13  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
14  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
15  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
16  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
17  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
18  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
19  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
20  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
21  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
22  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
23  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
24  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
25  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
26  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
27  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
28  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
29  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
30  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
31  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
32  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
33  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
34  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
35  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
36  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
37  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
38  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
39  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
40  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
41  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
42  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
43  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
44  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
45  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
46  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
47  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
48  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
49  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
50  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
51  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
52  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
53  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
54  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
55  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
56  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
57  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
58  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
59  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
60  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
61  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
62  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
63  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
64  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
65  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
66  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
67  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
68  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
69  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
70  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
71  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
72  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
73  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
74  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
75  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
76  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
77  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
78  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
79  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
80  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
81  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
82  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
83  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
84  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
85  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
86  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
87  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
88  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
89  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
90  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
91  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
92  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
93  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
94  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
95  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
96  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
97  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
98  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
99  com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
100 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
101 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
102 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
103 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
104 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
105 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
106 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
107 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
108 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
109 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
110 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
111 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
112 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
113 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
114 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
115 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
116 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
117 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
118 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
119 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
120 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
121 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
122 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
123 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
124 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
125 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
126 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
127 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
128 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
129 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
130 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
131 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
132 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
133 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
134 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
135 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
136 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
137 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
138 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
139 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
140 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
141 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
142 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
143 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
144 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
145 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
146 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
147 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
148 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
149 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
150 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
151 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
152 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
153 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
154 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
155 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
156 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
157 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
158 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
159 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
160 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
161 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
162 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
163 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
164 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
165 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
166 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
167 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
168 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
169 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
170 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
171 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
172 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
173 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
174 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
175 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
176 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
177 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
178 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
179 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
180 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
181 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
182 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
183 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
184 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
185 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
186 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
187 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
188 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
189 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
190 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddbf86 DSFSDB::_ScanDirectory_locked(char const*, DSFSDBNodeDir*, int, int) + 1606
191 com.apple.DebugSymbols        0x0000000101ddcd19 ___ZN6DSFSDB14WatchDirectoryEPKcb_block_invoke + 649
192 libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8da67323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
193 libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8da62c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
194 libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8da66365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
195 libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8da67ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
196 libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8da656b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
197 libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8da73fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
198 libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff95eea637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
199 libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff95ee840d start_wqthread + 13
```

I feel like it has to do with the _ScanDirectory_locked symbol but thats my only lead.

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ended up getting my answer from an apple eng. at the developers forum. This is a bug and I have opened a radar.(For apple to be able to handle this, you should add the output of "defaults read com.apple.dt.Instruments XRGlobalSearchPaths" if it happens to you)
There is a workaround to get you working: close instruments and xcode, run "defaults delete com.apple.dt.Instruments XRGlobalSearchPaths" and re-launch.